# Query to fetch the manager name by managerID

Tags: sql

I have a table named Employee and it has the fields as ID, Name, EmpID, rankID, DeptID and managerID.  I have set the managerID as a foreign key to the Employee table with reference to ID in employee table.  Now I want a query to fetch all the employee and their manager information.  The "manager information should be manager name not the managerID."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select e1.ID, e1.Name, e1.EmpID, e1.rankID, e1.DeptID, e2.name as managername
from employee e1
left outer join employee e2 on e1.managerID = e2.id
```

Comment: Shouldn't it rather be `left outer join employee e2 on e1.managerID = e2.id`?

Comment: It can just be a inner join employee e2 on e1.managerID=e2.ID